# What would you recommend to help with the current state of my mint plant?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, mint

[image]

My mint plant stem is turning brown and i had to take out all the dead leaves and I don’t know what to do. I think it was dry and put some water now, an it gets adequate sunlight near a window.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say it, but I would recommend a new plant. It's possible this one might grow more shoots from the rhizomes, but I wouldn't count on it. As to why your current plant is in this situation, I'm not sure. It could be a disease, overwatering, pests, or something. There might be something wrong with the soil.

If you're intent on saving this one, high amounts of light on the stem (which appears to be leafless) might help it to sprout new leaves.